# Responsive Menu Doesn't Toggle List Items

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

For whatever reason, when I add a radio check into the css, it will appear in the menu but will not show any of the menu items. Any tips on getting it to toggle properly would be a huge help!

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjjvp1bx/)

HTML

```
    <div id="nav">
         <nav id="nav" class="clearfix">
        <!-- nav menu top level -->
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle">
    <label for="button" onclick></label>       
<ul class="first-level">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  <li><a>Posts</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Listings</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
   </li>
  <li><a href="#">Photos</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About the Author</a></li>
  </ul>
          
        <?php get_search_form(); ?> </nav>
                                                               </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
#menu-toggle:checked + label + ul {
    display: block;        
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kjjvp1bx/3/

Or use jQuery, both works:

http://jsfiddle.net/kjjvp1bx/2/

Comment: Thank you! I am still learning how to do this and didn't realize I needed that. It looks like the jQuery version is showing the submenus too.

I added this to the non-js version for submenus.
    #menu-toggle:checked + label + ul ul{
    display: block;        
}

Comment: The only thing jQuery is doing is adding class "on" to the menu container. If you want to show submenus, you can change css to make submenus visible if a parent has class ".on"

Comment: Good to know. I've updated the project and it's working perfectly. Thank you! http://jsfiddle.net/casslt07/e85nt4q9/